# Adding a role using Members and Formidable Forms

Tags: user-roles

Not a coder :-(
Been using a snippet to change roles when someone completes a Formidable Forms. Works fine. But on another site, I want to just 'add' a role. I don't know how to modify the snippet below to add a given role rather than changing it.
One more idea... a way to protect more than just the admin role. I don't know how to modify the 'if' line so as to protect more than just the admins.
Thoughts?

````
/**
* This will change a user to a different member role after they complete their member profile.
*/
add_action('frm_after_create_entry', 'inactive_to_member', 20, 2);
function inactive_to_member($entry_id, $form_id){
 if($form_id == 21){ // form id of the form to copy
   $new_role = 'census_club'; //change this to the role users should be granted upon completing form

   $user = wp_get_current_user(); //get logged in user
   if(!$user) {
       return; //don't continue if user doesn't exist
   }

   $updated_user = (array)$user;

   // Get the highest/primary role for this user  
   $user_roles = $user->roles;
   $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
   if ( $user_role == 'administrator' ) 
       return; //make sure we don't downgrade any admins

   $updated_user['role'] = $new_role;
    
   wp_update_user($updated_user);
 }
}```
````

Comment: Members, Formiddable Forms and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: I tried all their support venues and got nowhere. Was here a few minutes and got an amazing reply. Also, I was not asking for help with a plugin, per se, it was the code I was after, understanding how to change a WP role. Anyway, sorry I polluted the stack but happy I did. Very happy indeed! Will try to better understand what is on topic going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the method  WP_User::set_role() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/set_role/

If you want to add the role as an additional role, replace `set_role` with `add_role`

```
add_action( 'frm_after_create_entry', 'inactive_to_member', 20, 2 );
function inactive_to_member($entry_id, $form_id) {
    if ( $form_id == 21 ) { // form id of the form to copy

        $user = wp_get_current_user(); //get logged in user
        if ( !$user ) {
            return; //don't continue if user doesn't exist
        }

        // Get user roles
        $user_roles = $user->roles;
        // Make sure they're not an administrator
        if ( !in_array( 'administrator', $user_roles ) ) {
            // Make Role Census Club         
            $user->set_role( 'census_club' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, fantastic. I can't thank you enough. Solved all my problems. Really grateful.